# jQuery drop down menu does not appear

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a drop-down menu using jQuery/JavaScript, but my menu won't show anything.

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
function toggleMenu(target){
    if($(target).css("display")=='none'){
        $("#drop_down, drop_menu").hide(500);
    $(target).toggle(500);
}
```

header.php

```
<?php

?>
<div id="header" class="absolute" >
    <ul>
        <li class="float_left"><p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_search')">Search</p></li>
        <li class="float_left"><p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_login')">Log in</p></li>
        <li class="float_left"><p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_chart')">My Cart</p></li>
        <li class="float_left"><p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_menu')">Menu</p></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="clear_both"></div>
     <br/>    
    <div id="drop_down"class="right">
        <div id="drop_search" class="hidden">
            <p>Search</p>
        </div>
        <div id="drop_login" class="hidden">
            <p>login</p>
        </div>
        <div id="drop_chart" class="hidden">
            <p>cart</p>
        </div>
        <div id="drop_menu" class="hidden">
            <p>menu</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sorry for the long css, i just like to pack it into one file

style.css

```
body{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
body th, body tr, body td{
    padding: 0;
}
body h1, body h2,body h3,body h4,body h5,body h6,body p{
    margin: 0px;

}
body p{
    font-size: 12px;
}
body h6{
    font-size: 14px;
}body h5{
    font-size: 16px;
}body h4{
    font-size: 18px;
}body h3{
    font-size: 20px;
}body h2{
    font-size: 24px;
}body h1{
    font-size: 28px;
}
body ul,body li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body img{
    border: none;
}
body hr{
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
}
body a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
body a:visited{}
body a:hover{}
body .relative{
    position: relative;
}
body .absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
body .fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
body .float_left{
    float: left;
}
body .float_right{
    float: right;
}
body .clear_both{
    clear: both;
}
body input, body select, body textarea{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
body .input_text{}
body .input_select{
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
body .input_option{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #333333;
}
body .input_option_inactive{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #888888;
}
body .input_submit{
    background: url("../images/submit.png");
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
body .input_submit:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #efefef;
}
body .input_submit_inactive{
    background: url('#');
    border:none;
}
body .input_submit_inactive:hover{
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #434343;
}
body .input_textarea{}
body .top{
    vertical-align: top;
}
body .middle{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body .bottom{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
body .left{
    text-align: left;
}
body .center{
    text-align: center;
}
body .right{
    text-align: right;
}
body .spacer{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
body .bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
body .italic{
    font-style: italic;
}
body .strip{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
body .hidden{
    display: none;
}
body .show{
    display: block;
}
body .pointer{
    cursor: pointer;
}
body .scroll-y{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#whole{
    width: inherit;
    height:100%; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.black{color: #000000;}
.white{color: #ffffff;}
.red{color: #ff0000;}
.green{color: #00ff00;}
.blue{color: #0000ff;}
.yellow{color: #ffff00;}
.toska{color: #00ffff;}
.pink{color: #ff00ff;}
```

header.css

```
#header{
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
 #header li{ height: 20px;
    background: #960000;
}
#header li p{
    margin: 0 15px;
    color: #cccccc;
    height: 12px;    
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header li p:hover{
    color: #f6f6f6;
}
#header #drop_down{
    background: url('../images/black20.jpg');
}
```

Can anyone can help ?

Comment: What does the css-class "hidden" contain?

Comment: does toggle remove your `class="hidden"` property?

Comment: do you get any error messages in your console (use a browser addon like firebug)

Comment: I had some issues when using `toggle` thus I'm not using it anymore and simply check whether the target is visible and hide it or not visible and show it...

Comment: @lindell : hidden class contain display: none; in my css
-diggersworld : it has to be like that but not work in my case
-DaniëlTulp : nope
-shadyyx : thanks for your information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sintaxe error in your function
Try with this function

> ```
> function toggleMenu(target){
>     if($(target).is(":hidden")){
>         $("#drop_down div").hide(500);
>     }
>     $(target).toggle(500);
> }
> ```

And give me some feedback...

Comment: thanks for your help, it's finally work, but somehow i must include <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"> from @Happy Singh to trigger it

can you explain it ? and can you explain why my code is wrong and how your code work ?, sorry i'm still newbie.

By the way, why my background from header.css still not show in my menu? :)

Comment: Yes, you are using the jQuery Library, you can download the javascript file and add in your site, or you can call outside from the google server. I believe that your css file dosen't work because you need to call it with this tag <link href="header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: if you post a link for your site, I can help you more. But you need some tutorial and read more about HTML, CSS and JavaScript for improve your skills. Try to use this website for testing some codes http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i just made the menu so far, so all you see above is whole of my code.
thanks @guilherme i'll do your recommendation and improve my skills more :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `class="hidden"` and set default to `style="display: none"` (or hide on page load).

Answer (score 0):

This code might work as per your requirement. I have not changed your code just remove class="hidden" entirely.

**Note:** You have not mention your css so i assume as per class names defined by you.

Please let me know if i am lagging some where....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
}
.pointer {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.absolute {
    position:absolute;
}
.float_left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.clear_both {
    clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" class="absolute">
  <ul>
    <li class="float_left">
      <p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_search');">Search</p>
    </li>
    <li class="float_left">
      <p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_login')">Log in</p>
    </li>
    <li class="float_left">
      <p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_chart')">My Cart</p>
    </li>
    <li class="float_left">
      <p class="pointer" onclick="toggleMenu('#drop_menu')">Menu</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id="drop_down" class="right">
    <div id="drop_search">
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drop_login">
      <p>login</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drop_chart">
      <p>cart</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drop_menu">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#drop_down div").hide();
function toggleMenu(target)
{
    if($(target).css("display") != 'none')
    {
        $(target).hide(500);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#drop_down div").hide(500);
        $(target).show(500);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sigh: if it run as one file, yes it work but if i run it in different file it's not work. by the way sorry i'm not mention the css before, now i've just add it above.

NOTE: i always like to split css, php, and jquery file.

Comment: finally it work, but i just take your "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" and combine it with @Guilherme codes, but some how the background from header.css still cannot show in the menu